# How to skip phrases when tokenizing sentences in OpenNLP?

Tags: java, nlp, text-mining, opennlp

I am using OpenNLP JAVA API for Sentence Tokenization and it is using space character to tokenize the sentence and is splitting every word.

Is there any way to i can skip the word splitting or tokenization for some specific words.

For Example in a sentence. "A quick brown fox jumping over the lazy dog". OpenNLP split/tokenize the sentence as

a
quick
brown
fox
jumping
over
the 
lazy
dog

i want to skip tokenization for the word "quick brown fox" and "lazy dog" , so the expected output will be

a
quick brown fox
jumping
over
the
lazy dog

Comment: By what criteria do you want to determine whether to split or not?

Comment: i can have a list of words to skip from another method or another way is to add tags before the words like #skip# quick brown fox #skip#, #skip# lazy dog #skip#

Answer (score 0):

One thought, since it appears you want to skip noun phrases, is to use the SentenceChunker to identify noun phrases. You can use the same spans/tokens in the sentence chunker that you get back from the tokenizer, and then adjust your array of tokens based on the chunk type. Take a look at this

[How to identify PP-tags/NP-tags/VP-tags in openNLP chunker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17035913/how-to-identify-pp-tags-np-tags-vp-tags-in-opennlp-chunker/21566109#21566109)

Comment: Mark, Thanks for ur suggestion unfortunately it is not specific to noun phrases as the sentences and skip words are dynamic and is up-to user content. I am already parsing the text before tokenization and remove the spaces and adding tokens to the skip words but was looking for a possible method or function within OpenNLP to reduce these additional steps.